# Angular 2 - Integrating angular universal in already built app on top of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, systemjs, angular-universal, angular-seo

We developed and deployed an angular 2 application using SystemJS which is built on the top of ASP.NET MVC and implemented AOT compilation for deployment to speed up the load time. All works well but we have a problem now with SEO as you may have guessed.

Now, to overcome this issue, we need to use angular universal to do some server prerendering. I'm not coming from the Nodejs background so apologies beforehand and I don't want to use/install a separate Nodejs server to do the prerendering on top of ASP.NET. Is there a way I can do some prerendering with (or without) angular universal using some other servers like the ASP.NET itself?

The initial load speed is already on target with AOT and its just the Facebook metatags that are creating an issue.

P.S: I'm using SystemJS and sorry for not including any code snippet at the time of asking this question as its more kind of an approach question than a coding bug. Thanks